# Правильное удаление указателей

Tags: c++

**Здравствуйте!**

У меня возник простой вопрос чисто академического характера. Допустим, где-то в коде происходит создание динамического массива:

```
 int *pi = new int[3];
```

Каким из трех способов обнулять динамический массив наиболее корректно/наиболее некорректно?

1. `delete pi;`
2. `delete [] pi;`
3. `delete [3] pi;`

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, интересно, что тогда в моем случае удалит первая конструкция?

Comment: Вроде как все будет зависеть от реализации компилятора.

Comment: Скорее всего первый элемент. Или UB.

Comment: @Asen, [вот здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/117208/) замечательно рассмотрен данный вопрос. 

А также внимательно прочитайте обсуждение и подумайте, насколько сложная в общем случае схема получается.

Comment: @avp, превосходная статья. Как раз точно по теме! Благодарю =)

Comment: Только вопрос не академического, а исключительно практического интереса.

Answer (score 6):

Первый удаляет указатель, а не массив. Второй удаляет массив. Ну а по поводу третьего, в С++ вроде не нужно указывать размер массива.

Так что правильно удалить ваш динамический массив можно вторым способом.

А лучше найди доку по этому вопросу там будет всё подробно расписано. Там вроде как если удаляешь со скобками то будут вызваны деструкторы если массив объектов.

Comment: Ведь уже вроде решили, что ничего точного по этому поводу сказать нельзя:

      Первый удаляет указатель

Поведение не определено.

Comment: Ну, имелось в виду, что нужно использовать `delete pi;` в случае, если раньше было написано `int* pi = new int;`

Answer (score 3):

Про третий способ первый раз слышу. Первые два для встроенных типов одинаковы. Точнее, стандартом это тоже не определено, но здравый смысл подсказывает, что по-другому быть и не может. Для классов, естественно UB.

Кстати, Боресков в своей книге "Расширения OpenGL" удаляет массив char для хранения пикселей изображения через delete, а не через delete[].

Comment: Интересно, это он допустил ошибку, или так принято поступать лишь элите? =)
   
      Кстати, Боресков в своей книге "Расширения OpenGL" удаляет массив char для хранения пикселей изображения через delete, а не через delete[].

Comment: Ну ошибся Боресков, описался. С кем не бывает.

Comment: >Интересно, это он допустил ошибку, или так принято поступать лишь элите? =)

 Элите так нельзя поступать. Это же UB как-никак, и неважно, что в большинстве реализаций поведение одно. Нельзя допускать даже маленькой вероятности ошибки.

>Ну ошибся Боресков, описался. С кем не бывает.

 Не описался, эта ошибка встречается неоднократно.

Comment: @GLmonster, **`UB`** это что? Неопределенное поведение?

Comment: Да - Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @GLmonster, разве возможная ошибка не относится к разряду "особо значимых", ведь, если в большинстве компиляторах это UB, то контроль над приложением явно теряется, а это не есть хорошо...

    Не описался, эта ошибка встречается неоднократно

Comment: Это как переходить дорогу не в положенном месте (не на переходе). 99%, что жить будете, но не дай Бог попасть в оставшийся 1%: последствия будут фатальны.

Comment: >разве возможная ошибка не относится к разряду "особо значимых", ведь, если в большинстве компиляторах это UB, то контроль над приложением явно теряется, а это не есть хорошо...

 Это по стандарту UB, но по-моему все основные компиляторы ведут себя одинаково, и ошибка не проявляется. А если вдруг подвернётся нестандартный компилятор, то ошибка сразу всплывёт. Но это в принципе не самая коварная ошибка, потому что отладчик практически сразу на неё укажет в таком случае.